# c program to decrement a large number with minimum execution time

Tags: c, gcc

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
unsigned int decrement(unsigned int value);
main()
{
    clock_t start, end;
    double cpu_time_used;
    register unsigned int value;
    value = 4294967;
    start = clock();
    decrement(value);
    end = clock();
    cpu_time_used = ((double) (end - start)) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
    printf("cpu_time_used %lf\n",cpu_time_used);
}

unsigned int decrement(register unsigned int value)
{
    int i;
    for(;value;value--)
    {
        printf("loop value %u\n",value);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I have tried to decrement a large integer value with less execution time, to achieve that i am declaring a variable with register keyword like **register unsigned int value** from this i have not received any optimization results while run this program with/without using this register keyword. please correct me if i am wrong. and **please share if we have any other method to decrement a larger number with minimum execution time.**

**program mentioned here is just for example with register keyword(one of the optimization method to reduce execution time) main agenda of this question is how to decrement a larger number with minimum execution time.**

Comment: The `register` modifier is only a suggestion, and one that compilers these days seldom care about.

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to do, or the relevance of a large number. You decrement `i` so what is the need to decrement `value` too? And why do you have a loop that runs `i>=0` but cause a `break` when `i==0`, wasting execution time in every iteration?

Comment: `value = value--;` makes no sense at all (just use `--value;`). And lose the `printf` in your loop, one execution of which is likely more time-consuming than your entire loop (i.e. you're measurement is literally nearly *all* IO-time). The test for `i==0` is worthless as well. You already cover that in your for-loop conditional if modified to be `i>0`.

Comment: `i=value;` fails with large values when `value > INT_MAX`.  Consider using consistent types.

Comment: Using `register` or not is insignificant compared to `printf("loop value %u\n",value);` which dominates CPU consumption.  Code will  not be able to assess optimization with that line of code there.

Comment: Do not edit your code in the question. If the issu has been solved, either accept the answer or leave a comment at your question.

Comment: Any compiler that wouldn't compile the simple `value -= 1` into the most efficient single-instruction decrement your processor has is not a compiler worth using.

Answer (score 1):

Without the understanding of the logic telling me the `decrement(x)` should be always zero, there is another problem:
`value = value--;` is invoking an undefined behaviour, as `value--` is a post decrement operation having side effects. You want either `value--;` or `value -=1`. But not both.

Answer (score 0):

When you're calling the `decrement` function, `value` is being passed in by value.  This means that the `value` you're modifying in the `decrement` function isn't the one with the `register` keyword associated with it.  You would would need to the decrementing in the same function that the `register` variable is define.

Even then, I question whether this is something you really need to do.  Seems like a classic case of premature optimization to me.

Answer (score 0):

`register` is commonly ignored by compilers... Anyway if something should be qualified `register` it is the variable `value` of the `decrement` function not the `value` of `main`. If you want to accelerate, why inserting an `if` inside the `for` loop? You may rewrite your code as :

```
unsigned int decrement(register unsigned int value)
{
    for(;value;value--)
    {
        printf("loop value %u\n",value);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Write slightly better code and let the compiler optimize...

Answer (score 0):

I would modify the decrement funtion like this:

```
unsigned int decrement(unsigned int value)
{
    for(value; value > 0; value--)
    {
       printf("loop value %u\n",value);
    }
    return value;
```

}

You dont need to say i >= 0 when you need that i is only > 0(see the  if with the break when i == 0 ), you don't even need "i" just do the operation with the variable value, since that's what you want to return( That's what I understand from your code) Sorry for my bad English!

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for my formatting as I am new here. 
Please change  `value = value--` to just `--value`
Unless you are using it in a definite way/statement, post-increment operator is usually slower than pre-increment operator. Same goes for decrement as well.
Also, you do not need to do an explicit check for `i>=0`
Try this:

```
unsigned int decrement(register unsigned int value)
{
    while(value>=0)
       printf("loop value %u\n",value--);
    return 0;
}
```